# is there a typesafe appraoch to ensure that a field of a case class can not be null in scala?

Tags: scala

As the question suggest, what are the different ways to ensure that someone, does not pass null to some of the field of let say a case class.

I know of require, but not a fan, because it blows an unchecked exception.

Comment: May I ask the context behind the question? Because you could _(should?)_ just assume that `null` doesn't exist in **Scala**. Especially for modeling data; if a field is optional use `Option`.

Comment: Sure. To be fair, it started as per my interaction with a java library that can return null for some of the function i am using. I need to build object (case class) out of the returns of those function, and did not want to put optionality in the field, because they are not optional. So obviously, i need to deal with the possibility of null before building my object. This is a separate concern in itself, but the thing that it made me think about was, what if i forget to do that, what if the java function is not explicit about the fact that it can return null ?

Comment: What if i was lazy and forget to look into the java code and realize that it can return null ? I just realize that constructing my object is not by definition super safe, hence i just wonder how to generally deal with that situation. I guess given the answer below there is no way. I need to be aware of it, and deal with that eventuality and return the exception/error as a value .

Comment: It seems also that even with the improvement of Scala 3, the problem remain the same, if null can be returned and you do not accept it as a field  value of your case class, well, you have to explicitly deal with it, to return the exception/error as a value, so you keep composing rather than relying on an exception being thrown.

Comment: Yes if you are dealing with a **Java** library you have to either check when `null` will be returned or juts assume it everywhere. This is in fact frustrating but it has worked well for the community for the last years.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't force it in `Scala 2` because of JVM limitations. However, in `Scala 3/Dotty` there is an interesting opt-in feature called Explicit Nulls.

You can check for more details here: http://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/other-new-features/explicit-nulls.html and here: http://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/internals/explicit-nulls.html

Essentially, you enable this feature with a compiler flag `-Yexplicit-nulls` and then your code doesn't compile if you violate non nullness:

```
val x: String = null // error: found `Null`, but required `String`

val x: String | Null = null // ok - Union type
```

Furthermore, they have additional type improvements for Null union types like Flow Typing and Equality.

The way it works is that compiler makes `Null` a subtype of `Any`, and not `AnyRef` like previously which forces compile time checks. But after erasure due to how JVM is implemented `Null` becomes a subtype of all reference types.

New hierarchy:

[image: New hierarchy]

After erasure:

[image: After erasure]

Regual practice in Scala is just not to use `null` and assume you have well behaved developers who do the same. Use `Option` instead. On the periphery if you don't trust users of your library/module/etc you can do runtime checks with `require`.